# Make an weighted histogram using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

So I want to create an histogram that is weighted, because I have some pixels that are more important than others. I want to give central area pixels a greater weight than the pixels on the borders, for example.

I am currently detecting an object with opencv cascadeClassifier and using numpy to generate a histogram of the target, but I want to give the pixels on the center area a greater weight than the others on the borders.

For example:

```
def generateHistogram(self,img):
    hist,bins = np.histogram(img.flatten(),256,[0,256])
    self.hist = hist
    #print hist
    return hist
```

So how can I do that? Is it called weighted histogram or does it have another name?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I think a more formal name for such a thing would be applying a statistical prior. This might be a common task in image processing that has its own nomenclature, but if you wanted to roll your own, you could generate a normal distribution centered around the center of your image, experiment with the variance, and weight each pixel by the distribution at that point.

Comment: On a related note, how about just looping through the image pixels?

Comment: @a-Jays hmm, but does the pixel distribution have spatial information? It's important to know which pixel is at the center and which one is on the borders.

Comment: You can always do that using the `(x,y)` of a pixel. My concern is efficiency.. as in, "is there a better way to do it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do if you just need something working without worrying much about the approach, get size of the image first in width and height. Now you know where is the center, let's say (x, y)th pixel it is.

Define a threshold(t) and a weight(w) for the pixels you want the special treatment on.

Very poor complexity here but depending on the size of your image and threshold value you will pick, it might not be all bad. In brief it would be something like this:

Go through all pixels that are at most (t) pixels away from your image center
 modify their value using the weight normalize(t * w)

One thing to note here is you might want to normalize resulting values between 0-256(or larger if you use more colors) to avoid overflow errors.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when I tried to build a weighted histogram of image's gradients phases: strong gradients should have proportionally more weight than weak gradients. I found out that NumPy had appropriate flag for `histogram` function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram

So I solved my problem with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# see tau manifest
TAU = np.pi * 2

# load image
#..

# calculate gradient
gradX = cv2.Scharr(image, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0)
gradY = cv2.Scharr(image, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=0, dy=1)

# calculate magnitude and phase
magnitude = cv2.magnitude(gradX, gradY)
phase = cv2.phase(gradX, gradY)

# build weighted histogram of phase
hist, bins = np.histogram(phase, bins=360, range=[0, TAU], weights=magnitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would like is to run each pixel through a kernel function like the gaussian or Epanechnikov kernel, to get your weighted color distribution. This is done in mean shift tracking. Exact formula can be found [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/lecture/meanshift.pdf), at page 7.

I am not aware of any functions in opencv that does just the histogram part, but you can refer to `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` or `sklearn.neighbors.kde.KernelDensity`for more information.